# Best way to save last duplicate Entry in a collection?

Tags: java, collections

A collection is given like - [10,11,5,6,10,11,10,11,10,5]
Answer should contains only last element(if element is repeated) 
Answer - [5,10,6,11]
 
here element(5) is repeated 2 times so answer should contain 2nd 5
similarly element(10) is repeated 4 times so answer should contain 4th 10
element(11) is repeated 3 times so answer should contain 3rd 11
 
Note : - here number of time of repetition of element is not matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain a Unique List in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259535/how-to-maintain-a-unique-list-in-java)

Comment: This question has been asked millions of times and if you google it the first link that comes up is the documentation to [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Please research before posting questions.

Comment: But Set is going to insert 1st element, after that if duplicates are coming it will not add , here my question is i have to save last entry not 1st

Comment: @Larrykuk You could construct a Map<Long, Long> with key = number and value = number of repetitions of that number. Then you can create your endresult list from the entrySet of that map.

Comment: When you say "last" and "first" I'm going to assume you are receiving an ordered Collection. If that's the case, why not traverse it and use a `Set` anyway? That way it's saving the "last" elements.

Comment: @px06 From the way I understand him (and the question isn't really clear) he wants to have a sorted list by the number of duplicates. So 10 is his first element because it exists 4 times in the original list, after that 11 with 3 appearances, 5 with 2 and 6 with only 1. When he says "last" i actually think he means "least appearing number"...

Comment: @911DidBush I see what you're saying, this question is very unclear but the solution you have suggested should be sufficient if that's what he's seeking.

Comment: @px06 solution suggested by you to reverse the order of given collection and use a set to traverse .. this way we can go ......any more way to go ......

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the list on the basis of number of repetitions.  As @px06 mentioned in the comments you can use set for unique and sorted values. But this will not give you result on the basis of number of repetitions.

```
Collections.frequency(List, value);
```

will give the frequency of value in the list. 
You need to iterate the list and then put the result into new collection.